# Prevent DialogFragment 'A' reappearing when selection made on DialogFragment 'B'

Tags: android, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment`, call it `A`, which presents an option that leads to a second `DialogFragment`, `B`, being displayed. `B` provides further options.

The functionality I require is as follows:

1. Making a selection in `A` leads to `B` being displayed (as stated above).
2. If the user hits `back` while `B` is being displayed, `A` should be resumed into view.
3. If the user makes a selection in `B`, then `B` should dismiss and `A` should not reappear.

In `A`, inside an `onItemClick()` handler I cause `B` to appear using:

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.remove(DialogFragmentA.this);
transaction.addToBackStack("transaction_label");
DialogFragmentB dialogFragment = DialogFragmentB.newInstance( ...some args here...);
dialogFragment.show(transaction, "frag_B");
```

I call `.addToBackStack()` as I understand this will cause the `back` key to pop and reverse the transaction. That is, replace `B` with `A` again.

So far, requirements 1 and 2 are met.

`B` makes use of `AlertDialog.Builder`. A positive button is used with listener. When that positive button is pressed, I want requirement 3 to be met. That is, `B` should dismiss and `A` should not reappear. But what actually happens is `A` appears again.

I am assuming here that within the implementation of `AlertDialog`'s positive button is a call to `dismiss()` which causes the back stack to be popped, resulting in `A` appearing again. Is this the case?

What I have tried to do is, within the positive button's `onClick()`, is to obtain the `FragmentManager` and call `.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)`. But this has no apparent effect; `A` continues to appear. Using `popBackStackImmediate()` has no effect either.

Is this perhaps because the event loop has already somehow committed to popping the back stack by the time the positive button listener's `onClick()` executes?

I'd be grateful for an explanation for what is occurring and how I can make it work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have nailed it, helped by the [question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598740/how-to-dismiss-a-dialogfragment-without-going-back-to-last-item-in-stack).

The key point is that the sequence of transactions is `nothing` -> `A` -> `B`. I want to pop the back stack to the point where I have `nothing`. Therefore, as well as calling `.addToBackStack()` for the `A` -> `B` transaction, I also need to call `.addToBackStack()` for the `nothing` -> `A` transaction. Then, all of those transactions can be popped off the back stack again to get back to the point of nothing: The first pop does `B` -> `A`, then the next pop does `A` -> `nothing`.

For both transactions I am now calling `.addToBackStack("some_transaction")`. In `B`'s positive `onClick()`, I call `manager.popBackStack("some_transaction", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`. I might rethink the tags I'm giving to the transactions, but this is now working as I want it to.

So the basic point seems to be that, if you want it to be possible to go `back` to a `DialogFragment` but also go back to the point where that `DialogFragment` wasn't shown at all, you have to add the transaction that put it there in the first place onto the back stack, so you can pop back to that point.

I previously thought it would be possible to achieve what I wanted by only adding the `A` -> `B` transaction to the back stack, and then somehow completely purging (rather than popping) the back stack to prevent `A` appearing again once a selection had been made in `B`. But it seems that there is no way to actually 'purge' the back stack; you can only pop and reverse the transactions.